# How do I beautify in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, webstorm

In Sublime 2, I know how to reindent the whole document and how to assign a key to this function, but I want to reindent as is do in WebStorm where spaces are added before and after a (=) or after and before a (:). Watch the image for the examples. How could I do that in Sublime or what package do this?

[image: Example of reindenting in WebStorm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use:

## [**HTML-CSS-JS Prettify**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify)

[image: Prettify]

---

You can adjust the following settings @:

```
Menu > Preferences > Package Settings > HTML/CSS/JS Prettify > Set Prettify Preferences
```

```
"js": {
  "allowed_file_extensions": ["js", "json", "jshintrc", "jsbeautifyrc"],

  "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline",
  // collapse:                 (old default) Put braces on the same line as control statements
  // collapse-preserve-inline: (new default) Same as collapse but better support for ES6 destructuring and other features. https: //github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues/231
  // expand:                   Put braces on own line (Allman / ANSI style)
  // end-expand:               Put end braces on own line
  // none:                     Keep them where they are

  "break_chained_methods":     false, // Break chained method calls across subsequent lines
  "e4x":                       false, // Pass E4X xml literals through untouched
  "end_with_newline":          false, // End output with newline
  "indent_char":               " ",   // Indentation character
  "indent_level":              0,     // Initial indentation level
  "indent_size":               2,     // Indentation size
  "indent_with_tabs":          true,  // Indent with tabs, overrides `indent_size` and `indent_char`
  "jslint_happy":              false, // If true, then jslint-stricter mode is enforced
  "keep_array_indentation":    false, // Preserve array indentation
  "keep_function_indentation": false, // Preserve function indentation
  "max_preserve_newlines":     0,     // Maximum number of line breaks to be preserved in one chunk (0 disables)
  "preserve_newlines":         true,  // Whether existing line breaks should be preserved
  "space_after_anon_function": false, // Should the space before an anonymous function's parens be added, "function()" vs "function ()"
  "space_before_conditional":  true,  // Should the space before conditional statement be added, "if(true)" vs "if (true)"
  "space_in_empty_paren":      false, // Add padding spaces within empty paren, "f()" vs "f( )"
  "space_in_paren":            false, // Add padding spaces within paren, ie. f( a, b )
  "unescape_strings":          false, // Should printable characters in strings encoded in \xNN notation be unescaped, "example" vs "\x65\x78\x61\x6d\x70\x6c\x65"
  "wrap_line_length":          0      // Lines should wrap at next opportunity after this number of characters (0 disables)
}
```

---

#### Note:

*It does not handle commas within quotes.

I also tested [**CoolFormat**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CoolFormat), which does not handle them either.*

Comment: Thank you @Enteleform . HTMLPrettify does exactly what I wanted. I can live without comma handling within quotes. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Will Bond's [**`Alignment`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Alignment) plugin, it should do most of what you want, and is pretty configurable as well. There seems to be an issue with the documentation and circular links between packagecontrol.io and wbond.net, but [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150825034957/http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) is the documentation stored in the Wayback Machine.